# Android: Debugging on device not connecting to local server

Tags: android

I am trying to debug sms receiving code on my device. What I did to test:

1. Connected OnePlus 5 device via USB and when I run from Android Studio, my app is loading on device
2. My phone and computer are on same wifi. Current API version is 23
3. I used ipconfig to find computer IP which is:

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dlink.router
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5cdf:e76e:cc32:31e5%5
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.109
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%5
                                   192.168.0.1
```

4. My web server is Apache running under xampp, port 80 on Windows 10
5. I can connect to my web server from emulator with URL:

   final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/myproject/api/";
6. Then to debug on device, I changed to:

   final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.9/myproject/api/";

But it is not connecting. It shows following error:

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.0.9:80
```

7. I also added Incoming rule for port 80 under firewall but still not connecting. What am I missing?

Comment: are you able to load your URL through chrome browser?

Comment: No, the URL was not working from chrome as well, means OS is blocking?

Comment: Means issue with your network. Disable firewall if possible and try again.